# How to use multiple passes of the FFMPEG filter functionality?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, youtube-dl

I know how to do this in multiple steps, but I'd rather do it in one pass so I'm not re-encoding it multiple times. It appears it is possible. . .

I have a playlist of my videos on YouTube that I want to run through the following process:

0. Download the videos from YouTube with [YouTube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md) and make them all the same format/codec (must be exactly the same since I concat them later)

   - `youtube-dl --merge-output-format mp4 -f "bestvideo+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best" -o "%(id)s.%(ext)s" -a playlist2.lst`
   - I know YouTube-dl uses [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) behind the scenes to process the video, but this command results in some MP4's that use **vp09** and others use **avcl** which requires the next step . . . .
1. Convert all videos to the same codec and format (some were MP4, MKV, or WebM)

   - `ffmpeg -i raw.mkv -preset slow -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -codec:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 4500k -minrate 4500k -maxrate 9000k -bufsize 9000k -vf scale=-1:1080 input.mp4`
2. Stretch any under sized videos to 1920x1080 then pad the videos to 1920:1200 with the video pushed to the top

   - `ffmpeg -i .\input.mkv -filter:v "pad=1920:1200:0:0" padded.mp4 -y` (only does the padding)
3. Add an image in the lower left corner

   - `ffmpeg -i padded.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:1090" watermarked.mp4`
4. Embed captioning text in the bottom (ideally not overlapping the watermark image, so bottom right)

   - `ffmpeg -i watermarked.mp4 -vf subtitles=inpyt.srt captioned.mp4`
5. Combine all the videos into one single MP4

   - `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.lst -c copy playlist.mp4`

It if has to be multiple re-encodings, what is the minimum number necessary? I'm interested both in time and in quality savings. I'm converting the videos to **MP4**, but I could use a different format/container like **mkv**, **webm**, or **m4v** if that would work better. Maybe having all the videos the same codec isn't required.

I'm running FFmpeg and YouTube-dl on Windows 10 but can run a script under Windows Subsystem for Linux or Powershell if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out

```
ffmpeg -i .\input.mp4 -i "watermark.png" `
-filter_complex "scale=-1:1080,pad=1920:1180:0:0:#01487e,overlay=0:1050,`
subtitles=test.srt:force_style=Fontsize=20"`
-codec:a aac -b:a 128k -codec:v h264_nvenc -pix_fmt yuv420p `
-b:v 4500k -minrate 4500k -maxrate 6000k -bufsize 9000k ./padded.mp4 -y
```

I was using a semicolon **`;`** instead of a comma **`,`** to chain multiple filters. The reverse apostrophe at the end of the line lets the command span multiple lines.